# How to opt-out system (http) cache on Android

Tags: android, caching

I have coded a reliable cache handler for my own needs. Problem is, Android still tries to cache stuff whenever I'm downloading from the Internet, thus creating cache files at the system level (and my app will never attempt to download the same thing again, thanks to my own cache management, rendering this system cache useless).

The android system cache can viewed at "Settings > Application Manager > MyAppName > Cache".

I wonder if there's a way to let Android know that I'm managing my own cache. By opting-out system cache, I'm hoping to see a (slight) performance boost, and some saved storage space.

Comment: "thus creating cache files at the system level" -- what is in these files? What are their names? Where are they located?

Comment: Is this HTTP cache or another protocol?

Comment: @CommonsWare I have no idea where the system level caches are saved, the only thing I can see is from Application Manager, it says "26 MB cached". This is HTTP.

Comment: Well, run your app on your emulator and go poking around your internal storage to determine what these files are.